Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open GPIO direction interface for pin [3]: No such file or directory
Any one to help me?
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioUtil;

public class DHT11 {
    private static final int MAXTIMINGS = 85;
    private final int[] dht11_dat = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private int pin = 3; // GPIO pin for DHT11 sensor data

    public DHT11(int pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
        // Setup wiringPi
        if (Gpio.wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
            System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO SETUP FAILED");
            return;
        }
        GpioUtil.export(3, GpioUtil.DIRECTION_OUT);
    }

    public String readTemp() {
        String result = "";
        int laststate = Gpio.HIGH;
        int j = 0;
        dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;

        Gpio.pinMode(pin, Gpio.OUTPUT);
        Gpio.digitalWrite(pin, Gpio.LOW);
        Gpio.delay(18);
        Gpio.digitalWrite(pin, Gpio.HIGH);
        Gpio.pinMode(pin, Gpio.INPUT);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            while (Gpio.digitalRead(pin) == laststate) {
                counter++;
                Gpio.delayMicroseconds(1);
                if (counter == 255) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            laststate = Gpio.digitalRead(pin);
            if (counter == 255) {
                break;
            }
            // Ignore first 3 transitions
            if (i >= 4 && i % 2 == 0) {
                // Shove each bit into the storage bytes
                dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
                if (counter > 16) {
                    dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }

        if (j >= 40 && checkParity()) {
            float h = (float) ((dht11_dat[0] << 8) + dht11_dat[1]) / 10;
            if (h > 100) {
                h = dht11_dat[0]; // For DHT11
            }
            float c = (float) (((dht11_dat[2] & 0x7F) << 8) + dht11_dat[3]) / 10;
            if (c > 125) {
                c = dht11_dat[2]; // For DHT11
            }
            if ((dht11_dat[2] & 0x80) != 0) {
                c = -c;
            }
            result = "Humidity = " + h + "% Temperature = " + c + "C";
        } else {
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean checkParity() {
        return dht11_dat[4] == (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3] & 0xFF);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int DHTpin = 3; // GPIO pin for DHT11 sensor data
        DHT11 dht = new DHT11(DHTpin);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(dht.readTemp());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

output: 
ilhamsyarief21@raspberrypi:~/INSTALL-JAVA $ javac -classpath ".:/opt/pi4j/lib/*" DHT11.java
ilhamsyarief21@raspberrypi:~/INSTALL-JAVA $ sudo java -classpath ".:pi4j-core.jar" DHT11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open GPIO direction interface for pin [3]: No such file or directory

    at com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioUtil.export(Native Method)
    at DHT11.<init>(DHT11.java:16)
    at DHT11.main(DHT11.java:80)
ilhamsyarief21@raspberrypi:~/INSTALL-JAVA $ ^C

I modified the code to use the correct GPIO pin (pin 3) and fixed the pin usage throughout the code. I expected that after this change, the program would be able to read data from the DHT11 sensor correctly. Previously, the program encountered errors due to using the wrong pin (pin 29). After fixing the pin usage, the program should run without errors and successfully read data from the DHT11 sensor.
